# add ::-moz-focus-inner using radium

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using Radium with react and I want to remove the dotted line appeared when element get focused. So the normal css do this is below.

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
```

Now the problem is as far as I know Radium only support `:hover` `:focus` `:active` pseudo selectors. Which means using `::-moz-focus-inner` selector is not possible.

So is there a way to remove the dotted line that appeared in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, there are 0 pseudo selectors supported by Radium other than the 3 emulated pseudo selectors for `:hover`, `:active`, and `:focus`.

However, the Radium team is discussing a new method for implementing pseudo selectors which would enable something like what you're asking for.  See this issue:
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/issues/510